# MVVM-Calling commands on child viewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Iam using MVVM and  have a main window with Close button and it is bound to the MainWindowViewModel's ICommand command.
In the main window there are two UserControl1 and UserControl2 which is bound to viewmodels UserControlVM1 and UserControlVM2 respectively.

UserControlVM1 and UserControlVM2 has command named CleanUp  that will clean up the resources.

So Whenever the close button is clicked on the mainwindow, i wanted to call the CleanUp command of Usercontrol viewmodels. How can we do this in XAML or any other alternatives?

Comment: Does your MainWindowVM has a reference to these sub-ViewModel ?
Something superior should have a reference to these so that MainWindowVM can know about them. Or Maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common implementation for communication between `ViewModel`s is the [Mediator Pattern](http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/mvvm-mediator-pattern/) which describes an object common between your `ViewModel`s providing a `Publish/Subscribe` model.  When an `Event` of interest occurs in an object it `publishes` a notification to the `Mediator`, one or more objects that are `subscribed` to that particular `Event` of the `Mediator` are then notified of the `Event` occurring in the original object.

[Mediator Pattern Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35277/MVVM-Mediator-Pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a view model first approach, in which case the `MainWindowViewModel` would have references to the `UserControlVM1` and `UserControlVM2`, and can call the `CleanUp` methods directly.

You should consider [using an MVVM framework if you're using MVVM](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could inspire yourself from a technique from [Prism's developer guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec3).

In Patterns and Practices' Prism Framework, [CompositeCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec2) allows several ViewModel to register their own command against a single CompositeCommand, so that all can be called with one single call.
You'd also need this global class that is referenced in all your ViewModels, but not necessarily a static one since you don't have loose coupled modules.